# Sum of all elements in a an array column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and have a use case to find the sum of all the values in a column. Each column is an array of integers.

```
df.show(2,false)

+------------------+
|value             |
+------------------+
|[3,4,5]           |
+------------------+
|[1,2]             |
+------------------+
```

Value to find 3 + 4 + 5 + 1 + 2 =  15

Can someone please help/guide me on how to achieve this?

Edit: I have to run this code in spark 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to sum up the `array` on each row and then compute the overall sum. This can be done with Spark SQL function [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#aggregate) available from Spark version 2.4.0.

```
val tmp = df.withColumn("summed_val",expr("aggregate(val,0,(acc, x) -> acc + x)"))

tmp.show()
+---+---------+----------+
| id|      val|summed_val|
+---+---------+----------+
|  1|[3, 4, 5]|        12|
|  2|   [1, 2]|         3|
+---+---------+----------+

//one row dataframe with the overall sum. collecting to a scalar value is possible too.
tmp.agg(sum("summed_val").alias("total")).show() 
+-----+
|total|
+-----+
|   15|
+-----+
```

Another option is to use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#explode). But beware this approach will generate a large amount of data to be aggregated on.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
val tmp = df.withColumn("elem",explode($"val"))
tmp.agg(sum($"elem").alias("total")).show()
```